# What is view engine in spring mvc Java and how it's works?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I heard the term 'thymeleaf' as view engine.
But I don't know where it's working in web application please clarify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are more commonly called template engines, and provide tools to display the data contained in your Java objects into dinamically generated HTML.

A quick example so you understand what that means, you have a `@Controller` with this one mapping:

```java
@GetMapping("/example")
public String getExample(Model model) {
    List<ExampleDTO> list = exampleService.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("list", list);
    return "list-all";
}
```

`ExampleDTO.java` has two string attributes "name" and "label". And you have an HTML template (`list-all.html`) like this:

```html
...
<div th:each="item : ${list}">
    Name: <span th:text="${item.name}"></span><br>
    Label: <span th:text="${item.label}"></span>
</div>
...
```

Here `th:each` and `th:text` are both evaluated by Thymeleaf and replaced with HTML. `th:each` will iterate through a collection and generate as many elements as `collection.size()` while `th:text` simply replaces the content of the tag with the attribute value of the Java object.

In the end the browser will receive an HTML like the following (imagine the list contained 3 items):

```html
...
<div>
    Name: <span>Item 1</span><br>
    Label: <span>IT1</span>
</div>
<div>
    Name: <span>Item 2</span><br>
    Label: <span>IT2</span>
</div>
<div>
    Name: <span>Item 3</span><br>
    Label: <span>IT3</span>
</div>
...
```

Thymeleaf is very powerful, more info [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/).